# In Postal III, how can I pour gasoline on objects farther away than my own toes?

Tags: postal-3

I just bought Postal III and played through most of the introduction level. At one point, the Postal Dude has to douse three zombies with gasoline and set them on fire. I took me a long time to get all three zombies because the gas just seems to dribble out of the can and onto the ground around the Postal Dude's feet.

How can I increase the range of the gasoline flow? I'm setting *myself* on fire more often than enemies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, apparently, just make sure you don't stand on the gasoline yourself when tossing the match...

Comment: That sucks. I was gyrating like an over-caffeinated squirrel for 20 minutes to try to give the gas a little momentum, and all for nothing!